# How to get current list of decorations OR handle decoration position change in VSCode Extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, text-decorations, gutter

Lets take this example into account.
I have a file with contents:

```
  1: one
  2: two
  3: three
```

and I create a line decoration for line "two":

```
const position = new vscode.Position(1, 0);
const range = new vscode.Range(position, position);

const decoration = vscode.window.createTextEditorDecorationType({
  gutterIconPath: context.asAbsolutePath('images/icon.svg')
});

vscode.window.activeTextEditor?.setDecorations(decoration, [range]);
```

that gives me

```
  1: one
* 2: two
  3: three
```

**Next step**:
I am changing file contents by adding a new line before line "two".
After that file looks like this:

```
  1: one
  2: 
* 3: two
  4: three
```

As you can see VSCode has updated my line decoration and now it is positioned on line 3 (instead of 2) which is totally correct and I've expected that.

**And now the question**:
how can I get this current updated position of my line decoration?
If I hold the `range` reference - it is still pointing to line 2.

What is the right way to handle this decoration changes?

Either of these 2 options would satisfy me:

1. a way to query all the current decoration positions displayed for currently open file
2. a way to subscribe to `decoration` / `range` changes so that I can handle those manually.

Maybe I am totally wrong and it should be done in another way.
Please advise!

Answer (score 2):

So apparently there is no way to get all the current decorations for open file in VSCode. Here is an old issue without clear plans to be resolved https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/54147.

I've found an internal method `getLineDecorations` - https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/master/src/vs/editor/browser/widget/codeEditorWidget.ts#L1118 - and I was trying to reach to it via

```
vscode.window.activeTextEditor?._proxy
vscode.window.activeTextEditor?._runOnProxy
```

but I did not succeed.

So for now probably the only option that we have mentioned here https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/54147#issuecomment-439177546 is:

- to store a copy of all decoration positions
- to update it manually on each text update via `vscode.workspace.onDidChangeTextDocument` handler

It is doable but very annoying that we have to do this stuff manually. ¯_(ツ)_/¯
Also very error prone )